# Photo library is displayed behind the popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8

I am opening `photo library` from a button in UIPopover, but photo library is displayed behind the popover.

I am presenting popover as follow.

```
[self.commentsPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rectInSuperview inView:self.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

`self.commentsPopover` is `UIPopoverController`.

After popover is displayed, I am opening photo library against button in popover.

```
self.attachmentPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initImagePicker];
self.attachmentPicker.maximumImagesCount = MAX_ATTACHMENT_COUNT; 
self.attachmentPicker.returnsOriginalImage = NO; //Only return the fullScreenImage, not the fullResolutionImage
self.attachmentPicker.imagePickerDelegate = self;
self.attachmentsView.delegate = self;
self.attachmentPicker.modalInPopover=YES;
self.attachmentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[MKGlobals presentViewController:self.attachmentPicker animated:YES completion:^{
    self.attachmentPicker = nil;
}];
```

This displays photo library behind the popover.

Follow image describes scenario. 
[image]

**This code is working fine in iOS < 8.x.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to present over `self.commentsPopover`, instead of `MKGlobals`?